# Kafka Streams: RocksDB TTL

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I understand that the default TTL is set to infinity (non-positive).  However, if we need to retain data in the store for max of 2 days, can we do the override with the RocksDBConfigSetter interface implementation, that is options.setWalTtlSeconds(172800)?  OR would it conflict with the Kafka streams internals?

Ref:
https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html#streams-developer-guide-rocksdb-config

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kafka Streams - Low-Level Processor API - RocksDB TimeToLive(TTL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43860114/kafka-streams-low-level-processor-api-rocksdb-timetolivettl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not possible. Kafka Streams disables RocksDB's TTL feature in a hard-coded way for various technical reasons. There is also a ticket for this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4212

For now, you could use a windowed store to expire old record after 2 days. Ie, you do a `stream.groupByKey().windowedBy(...).reduce(...)` with a `TimeWindow` of 1ms and a "dummy" reduce that just return the latest value for a key.

Comment: Hi Matthias, thanks.  Since the store is enriched through low level processor API, please suggest if there is a workaround similar to the above high level DSL.  If not, I understand that there is a open ticket, I plan to iterate through the key value store in a specific frequency to delete them

Comment: You can also create a windowed store instead of a plain key-value store via Processor API.

Comment: Hi Matthias, I'm facing the similar problems. I have `windowedBy()` function in my topology with 1 hour time window. But when I check the disc usage, the `/tmp/kafka-streams` folder keeps increasing. From 5G to 20G in 24 hours. How often will rocksdb remove the old data? Thanks!
My code is like `.windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofMinutes(60)).grace(Duration.ZERO))
 .reduce((event1, event2) -> event2)`

Comment: By default, retention time is 24h. You can configure it via `reduce(..., Materialized.as(null).withRetention(...))`.